# How to use pg_restore to import dump file in cloudsql?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I want to import the .sql file created with pg_dump into cloudsql.

The console and gcloud commands are both custom-type dump files, so they are told to use pg_restore.

On my local machine

```
pg_restore -h cloud_sql_ip -U postgres -d database sqlfile.sql
```

When I use the command, I get the following error:

```
pg_restore: error: connection to database "database" failed: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
        Is the server running on host "cloud_sql_ip" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

If I use the gcloud sql connect command, it will connect without any problems.

I don't know why I am getting the error.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You mentioned custom format, wouldn't that mean you should use the second command in the doc? [1]

[1]https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/importing#pg_restore

Comment: My dump file is in .sql file format, so the second method doesn't work... Am I thinking wrong??

Comment: @DevinTaylor Neither of their instructions for using pg_restore make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use PostgreSQL's pg_restore with `-d`, it needs to be able to connect to the database, which apparently it can't, probably due to firewall issues.

Perhaps you can change the config to let you connect from your own computer (I don't know, I'm not a Google Clouse user.)

Another option would be use pg_restore without `-d` to convert the custom dump file into a real sql file, then load that real sql file using one of the other methods you already tried but which failed because it was the wrong format.

```
pg_restore -f real_sql.sql sqlfile.sql
```

Or you could just re-run pg_dump, choosing the plain format not the custom format this time.

Comment: This dump file is already created in a database called chembl. It was a .dmp file when downloaded, but it was put in my DB and pg_dumped in .sql file format. But it's still a custom-format file. Can I dump it to a standard file?

Comment: Yes, that is what the command I showed, using pg_restore with -f, does.

Comment: If you loaded it to your own database, it doesn't remember how it got there.  If it dumped out again as a custom format, it is because you told it to use that format when dumping it, not because it remembers that that was what it was before it was loaded.

Comment: thank you. Although it was not possible to import into pg_restore, uploading from console works normally after changing to standard file.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL's pg_restore -d from your local (On my local machine) requires you to first authorize **your** public IP, there by allowing your machine to connect to your cloudsql instance...

Per GCP

> You have not authorised any external networks to connect to your Cloud
> SQL instance.

If you click on the Connections link on the left nav, under the Networking tab, you will see the above message...you will need to add your pubic IP (click Add Network)

[image]

Hopefully this helps

Comment: If you are concerned about security: This should work but be carefull you do this with your office/home computer since the public ip is shared between multiple computers/may change if it is not a static ip. So either accept an ip from a vm with a static ip or allow your ip just for this operation and remove it after.